# AJAX object in Safari and Chrome?

Tags: ajax, safari, google-chrome

I asked,

> Can you tell me why my searches are working ok in IE8 but get stuck with safari and chrome?
>
> www.netivot.biz
>
> The ajax code is at www.netivot.biz/js/Ajax.js
>
> It works with some xml and xslt files

then jitter suggested to preplace my code with :

```
function getAjaxObject() {
  var xmlHttp = null;  
  try {    
    //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome, IE7+
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
 } catch(e) {    
     try {      
       //IE6+
          xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    
     } catch(e) {
          try {
            //IE5+
            xmlHttp  = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          } catch(e) {
            xmlHttp  = null;
          }
     }
 }  
 return xmlHttp;}
```

but still dont work on safari and chrome any advise?

Comment: Do not re-ask your old question. Edit your old question and note that you updated with (with **update** maybe). You may as well delete 3 of the 4 questions you have that are basically about the same thing.

Comment: which one is his old question?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one out, it has the benefit of not being browser dependent.

```
 // Browser-agnostic factory function
 _createXMLHttpRequest: function() {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     return new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
   } else {
     _error("Could not create XMLHttpRequest on this browser");
     return null;
   }
 },
```

More information:

- http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Browser_Component
- http://ajaxify.com/run/testAjaxCaller/

Answer (score 3):

Would you try using [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) or some other library's ajax functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
  }
}
</script>
```

this piece of code is available in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/) you can learn basics here like i did. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. All the suggestions shall work. Anyway, here is what I use and it works at least for my websites.

```
return window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"): new XMLHttpRequest()
```