# Alternative to XRM Javascript calling webservice using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, web-services, activex, dynamics-crm-2011, xrm

I have a problem on CRM javascript when calling a webservice from browsers other than IE. See my code below for the web service call implementation.

```
function RetrieveMultipleEntity(targetEntity, conditionAttributeName, conditionAttributeValue, targetId, targetAttribute)
{
// Prepare variables to retrieve the contacts.
var authenticationHeader = GenerateAuthenticationHeader();

// Prepare the SOAP message.
// var xml = (the SOAP message)

var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

xHReq.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/RetrieveMultiple");
xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
xHReq.send(xml);
// Capture the result.
var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;

return resultXml;
}
```

There's a problem on this line:

```
var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
```

It runs correctly on IE because it can use ActiveXObject but unfortunately it fails on Firefox/Chrome. I'm looking for suggestions on an alternative of calling the web service. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX object in Safari and Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697188/ajax-object-in-safari-and-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
var xHReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

it works also for  IE7+